# Graphing a single Y point on an already established line graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm currently attempting to streamline our firefighting foam tests at the fire station. I've been successful in making a line graph or XY Scatter Plot to graph our conductivity test (foam has to be tested at 2% concentration, 3% concentration, and 4% concentration). The next step in the process is to flow the foam from whatever discharge (for example, a bumper turret), and test the conductivity of the foam flowing. This allows us to test the truck to ensure it is making the adequate concentration of foam for the FAA requirements.

I'm struggling to find a way of plotting the final conductivity point, a Y coordinate without a defined x coordinate, where the X coordinate would be obtained from where the Y coordinate is plotted on the line. I've been able to have it plot a point on the graph, but can't find a way to have the point be tied to whichever foam test conductivity line it should be. I've attached a hand drawn graph of what we're trying to accomplish for clarification purposes. Essentially, it's a really long process to determine what the percentage of foam the truck is flowing, which is only obtainable from plotting the conductivity (Y Coordinate) on the established line graph, and then determining what the foam percentage (X Coordinate) is
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm obviously way above my Excel level at this point. I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I find [Origin](http://www.originlab.com/) to be more useful in plotting complicated graphs than Excel, one thing I learned recently while doing my project.

Comment: Switching systems isn't really an option for the guys here at the station. Convincing the powers at be to spend money on new software almost certainly wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will do this easily for you.

1. Add your **Control Data**.  Just like the table on your form, you'll need two columns `Control, Value` and then their values below.
2. Convert your **Control Data** into an Excel Table `Insert>Tables>Table` for your control values (not absolutely required, but a best practice).
3. Add your **Test Data**.  To get it like you've presented on your form, you'll need three columns `Test Label, Test X, Test Y`.
4. Convert your **Test Data** into an Excel Table (same as step #2).
5. Create a blank XY/Scatter Chart `Insert>Charts>Scatter>Scatter with Straight Lines & Markers`.
6. Add your **Control Data** series, with
   `Series X Values = Control column`
   `Series Y Values = Value column`
7. Add each of your test values as a separate series
   `Series Name = Test Label`
   `Series X Values = Test X`
   `Series Y Values = Test Y`
   This will allow you label them independently.  It's not the most efficient method, but for a few data points it's not too bad.  If you want a more efficient method, comment below and I'll give you another option.
8. Format everything to taste.  If you want to recreate the exact look of the form it's possible, you'll just need to adjust the horizontal and vertical axis values and format everything to match the original.  Once you get the hang of it, it'll take about 10 minutes to set everything to look like this:

[image: foam test chart]

**Update**

To automatically calculate the concentration (X) value, based upon the provided information, I recommend adding one additional table (it'll make things easier to keep track of).

We'll use the line formula `y=mx+b` to calculate the concentration (X) value for your known conductivity (Y) value.  However, since your original data line has two segments (one from 2%-3%, the other from 3%-4%), you'll need to calculate slope (m) and intercept (b) for each segment.  Luckily Excel has formulas for that.

1. Create a new table with three columns
   `Segment Label, Slope (m), Intercept (b)`.
2. Add two rows, one for your
   `2% Segment` and `3% Segment`.
3. Calculate slope (m) for each segment using data from your original table:
   2% formula `=SLOPE({1.01,1.36},{0.02,0.03})`
   3% formula `=SLOPE({1.36,1.65},{0.03,0.04})`
4. Calculate intercept (b) for each segment using data from your original table:
   2% formula `=INTERCEPT({1.01,1.36},{0.02,0.03})`
   3% formula `=INTERCEPT({1.36,1.65},{0.03,0.04})`
5. In the Test Data Table you'll calculate your Concentration (Test X) value based upon your known Conductivity (Test Y) value.  However, since you have two line segments with different slopes and intercepts, you'll need to pick the appropriate slope and intercept based upon your Conductivity.  So we'll insert an IF statement to determine which set to use:
   `=IF([@[Test Y]]<1.36,([@[Test Y]]-'2% intercept')/'2% slope',([@[Test Y]]-'3% intercept')/'3% slope')`
   where you replace the items in '' with the appropriate cell references (or better yet, named ranges).

If you add the additional table with slope and intercept, and replace the **Test Data Table** values with the formula in Step 5, your chart should remain the same and any new rows you add to the **Test Data Table** should automatically calculate the concentration for the provided conductivity.

Also, FWIW, don't be surprised if Excel rounds or calculates slightly different to the second or third decimal.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I'm curious about, where you input the Test X values manually, is there a way to make it graph the Test Y values on the line without putting those in? The Test X Values aren't known until it's graphed on the line and you see where the intersect point is.

Comment: Yes, it can be calculated by formula as long as are you certain it will always fall on the line and you just need the correct pressure (X) value.  If it could fall off of the line, you'd need more info than you provided to determine.  I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you sir! It always falls on the line for the final step. It's basically just a long and ridiculous process to determine the final X value.

Comment: Don't want to annoy you about it, but just curious if you had a chance to update that formula in the answer yet?

Comment: Working on it now.  I'll post shortly.

Comment: You're my hero.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for and needed it to do. I'll implement it tomorrow when I'm on duty and let you know the final result. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that it worked perfectly. I tweaked some of the test labels and added more test parameters as a new series, and everything works great. I set it up to be based off of the cells so that it updates automatically like we wanted so we can use it as a template. You're a life saver. It would have taken me forever to come up with the formula and make it work.

Comment: It's in the comments. You use the SLOPE and INTERCEPT formulas built into Excel.